# PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on macOS (works if I do not use sudo)

Tags: ios, macos, environment-variables, sudo

I am doing:

```
conda activate my_env
export PYTHONPATH=/{muy_path}/src:$PYTHONPATH
python src/main.py
```

and all works fine.

But if I do:

```
conda activate my_env
export PYTHONPATH=/{muy_path}/src:$PYTHONPATH
sudo python src/main.py
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

If I use printenv PYTHONPATH is listed as defined, but if I do sudo printenv, then PYTHONPATH is not on the list.

How can I run the script using sudo, but at the same time conserving the PYTHONPATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way by running the script this way:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/{muy_path}/src:$PYTHONPATH python src/main.py
```